# How to do this query in background with AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've made this code:

```
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    Button search = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cerca);
    andata = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.andata);
    ritorno = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ritorno);
    //set adapters

    ParseQuery<ParseObject>query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Stations");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)
        {
            if(e == null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    String name = list.get(i).getString("code");
                    StationNames.add(name);

                }

                String [] strAdapter = new String[StationNames.size()];
                strAdapter=StationNames.toArray(strAdapter);
                ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strAdapter);
                andata.setAdapter(adapter);
                ritorno.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            else
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

and the problem is that there are 50k stations to download from Parse..my question is: it's possible to start this download after 3 character written? For example after digit "Pin" the query to Parse starts...
Thank you

Comment: see `setThreshold`

Comment: @pskink in xml or java?

Comment: I put android:completionThreshold="3" in xml.. so I don't change anything in the query, sure?

Comment: basically there is no need to download 50k stations and keep it in array adapter, it is simply waste of memory, you should query each time you type something in your `ACTV`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) for a complete working code

Comment: but if I use threshold(3) it download 50k in the same mode?

Comment: threshold has nothing to do with your 50k download, just do not download all the stations but only those that match the text entered in `ACTV`

Comment: I see your link but I don't understand how to do a Filter in the query, for example "Milan" station.. i would start query when user digits "Mil"..I have to receive this "Mil" from ACTV and do in query ".whereEqualTo("code","Mil"); ?

Comment: do you see `runQuery` method? it has `CharSequence constraint` parameter holding your "Mil" string, now you can call a query that returns all the data starting (or containing) that string, i have no experience with `ParseQuery` though